# How do I pass a struct as an argument in delegatecall to a proxy library?

Tags: solidity, struct, delegatecall, library, abi.encodewithsignature

I am trying to call the `buyAssetsForEth` function in the `OpenSeaMarketV2` library using delegatecall as follows:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract Owned {
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}

contract Router is Owned {
    struct OpenSeaBuy {
        address a;
    }

    address public openSeaMarketV2 = 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138;

    constructor() Owned(msg.sender) public {
    }

    function buyAsset(OpenSeaBuy memory openSeaBuys, bool revertIfTrxFails) public payable {

        (bool success, bytes memory result)=openSeaMarketV2.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("buyAssetsForEth((address),bool)",openSeaBuys,revertIfTrxFails));
        require(success, 'Delegate Call failed');

    }

    receive() payable external {}

    function contractAddress()
    external view
    returns (address)
    {
        return address(this);
    }

}
```

The `OpenSeaMarketV2` library is deployed separately to `0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138`

```
library OpenSeaMarketV2 {

    struct OpenSeaBuy {
        address a;
    }

    function buyAssetsForEth(OpenSeaBuy memory openSeaBuys, bool revertIfTrxFails) public {
        uint256 x = 3;
    }
}
```

But the execution of `buyAsset` fails with the message: "Delegate Call failed"

Any ideas on why it is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just encountered one of the caveats of library ABI encoding. You can read about it [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html#function-signatures-and-selectors-in-libraries). Essentially, this line related to libraries function selectors is the explanation :

> Non-storage structs are referred to by their fully qualified name,
> i.e. C.S for contract C { struct S { ... } }.

Meaning that the function selector for OpenSeaMarketV2.buyAssetsForEth is not computed from :

- `keccak256(buyAssetsForEth((address),bool))` : 0x443e309e

but rather from :

- `keccak256(buyAssetsForEth(OpenSeaMarketV2.OpenSeaBuy,bool))` : 0x2baccc78

This is a library specific encoding scheme. To solve your issue, there are two main ways. Either change your signature string to explicitly use the one that the library was compiled with :

```
function buyAsset(OpenSeaBuy memory openSeaBuys, bool revertIfTrxFails) public payable {

    (bool success, bytes memory result)=openSeaMarketV2.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("buyAssetsForEth(OpenSeaMarketV2.OpenSeaBuy,bool)",openSeaBuys,revertIfTrxFails));
    require(success, 'Delegate Call failed');
}
```

Or refer directly to the library function selector for a slightly more concise syntax but definitely less error prone :

```
function buyAsset(OpenSeaBuy memory openSeaBuys, bool revertIfTrxFails) public payable {

    (bool success, bytes memory result)= openSeaMarketV2.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSelector(OpenSeaMarketV2.buyAssetsForEth.selector,openSeaBuys,revertIfTrxFails));
    require(success, 'Delegate Call failed');
}
```

I hope that answers your question.